# Using TOTP for keepass database

Tags: one-time-password, keepass

With OtpKeyProv-Plugin it is possible to lock the database with HOTP-passwords. I'm searching for possibility to lock my database with time-based passwords. It would allow to generate the keys on multiple devices (yubikey, google authenticator..) and use synchronized keepass-databases on multiple devices (pc, laptop, smartphone). I'm aware of confusion with this setup and different HOTP counter.

Is there a possibility to use TOTP-passwords with keypass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its impossible due to the fact, that keepass would need to save the secret in case of TOTP, while with HOTP, there is no need to save the secret.

Here is the exact description from the developer:
http://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/cbebb317#f7c6